# Longest Consecutive Days Count for BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, gaps-and-islands

Right now I just have an aggregate of how many days a user has worked. I'm trying to change this query to most continuous days worked.

Where **u12345** would be `4` and **u1** would be `2`.

Is this possible to do with a BigQuery statement?

**EDIT** I am [Kind of close](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/viMk3UACEo9yfaNneXWPks/3) with the following query but my **u1** is getting 3 instead of 2.

```
SELECT MIN(e.timestamp) as date_created, e.uid, COUNT(e.uid) + 1 AS streak
FROM OnSite e
LEFT JOIN OnSite ee 
  ON e.uid = ee.uid 
AND DATE(e.timestamp) = DATE(DATE_ADD(ee.timestamp, INTERVAL -1 DAY))
WHERE ee.uid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY e.uid;
```

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE OnSite
    (`uid` varchar(55), `worksite_id`  varchar(55), `timestamp` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO OnSite
    (`uid`, `worksite_id`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-01'),
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-02'),
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-03'),
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-04'),
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-06'),
  ("u1", "worksite_1", '2019-01-01'),
  ("u1", "worksite_1", '2019-01-02'),
  ("u1", "worksite_1", '2019-01-05'),
  ("u1", "worksite_1", '2019-01-06')

;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT    uid, COUNT(DISTINCT timestamp) Total
FROM      OnSite
GROUP BY  uid;

| uid    | Total |
| ------ | ----- |
| u1     | 4     |
| u12345 | 5     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/viMk3UACEo9yfaNneXWPks/2)

Comment: Maybe you need to process data after the query. I don't know query to do that.

Comment: @Cochu I added an edit that I'm getting close but I'm one number off

Comment: u12345 would be 3, not 4 because "2019-01-04" doesn't have next day

Comment: The thought is that 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-04 is 4 consecutive days. So it would be 4 @cochu

Comment: I think you will either need a stored procedure or some application code as to do this requires looping through all the data. The reason `COUNT` doesn't work is because your `u1` has more than one streak, and days from both streaks are being counted in your result.

Comment: @Nick hmm, well my current result is just counting total days all together. But I see what you mean. Would it be possible to just list both streaks? It would suck to  get 5 years worth of data for every single user and code a consecutive day streak

Comment: please check my answer. It gives you expected result with no use of stored procedures

Comment: It does seem @Simonare has proved me wrong as long as you are using MySQL 8

Comment: It appears so, unfortunately this was for BigQuery and it doesn't like it. But I never mentioned it @Nick

Comment: @bryan If the answer doesn't actually solve your problem you should leave the question open so you can possibly get a solution which does work for you (you can just upvote the answer instead). I've added the `bigquery` tag to your question so that answers should be limited to code that works there.

Comment: @Nick I appreciate that nick, I've left the question open

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

In case if you are interested in max consecutive days of the users on the same worksite:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT uid, MAX(consecuitive_days) max_consecuitive_days
FROM (
  SELECT uid, grp, COUNT(1) consecuitive_days
  FROM (
    SELECT uid, 
      COUNTIF(step > 1) OVER(PARTITION BY uid, worksite_id ORDER BY ts) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT uid, worksite_id, ts, 
        DATE_DIFF(ts, LAG(ts) OVER(PARTITION BY uid, worksite_id ORDER BY ts), DAY) step 
      FROM `project.dataset.table`
    )
  ) GROUP BY uid, grp
) GROUP BY uid
```

In case if worksite does not matter and you are looking just for max consecutive days:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT uid, MAX(consecuitive_days) max_consecuitive_days
FROM (
  SELECT uid, grp, COUNT(1) consecuitive_days
  FROM (
    SELECT uid, 
      COUNTIF(step > 1) OVER(PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY ts) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT uid, ts, 
        DATE_DIFF(ts, LAG(ts) OVER(PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY ts), DAY) step 
      FROM `project.dataset.table`
    )
  ) GROUP BY uid, grp
) GROUP BY uid
```

You can test, play any of above with he sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'u12345' uid, 'worksite_1' worksite_id, DATE '2019-01-01' ts UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u12345', 'worksite_1', '2019-01-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u12345', 'worksite_1', '2019-01-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u12345', 'worksite_1', '2019-01-04' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u12345', 'worksite_1', '2019-01-06' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u1', 'worksite_1', '2019-01-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u1', 'worksite_1', '2019-01-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u1', 'worksite_1', '2019-01-05' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u1', 'worksite_1', '2019-01-06' 
)
SELECT uid, MAX(consecuitive_days) max_consecuitive_days
FROM (
  SELECT uid, grp, COUNT(1) consecuitive_days
  FROM (
    SELECT uid, 
      COUNTIF(step > 1) OVER(PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY ts) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT uid, ts, 
        DATE_DIFF(ts, LAG(ts) OVER(PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY ts), DAY) step 
      FROM `project.dataset.table`
    )
  ) GROUP BY uid, grp
) GROUP BY uid
```

with result:

```
Row uid     max_consecuitive_days    
1   u12345  4    
2   u1      2
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. This improved my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you Mikhail! This works exactly as expected. I did have a question about what you meant by for the `users on the same worksite` bit. I'm having trouble understanding what is going on here. It works a bit differently if I were to add `FROM project.dataset.table WHERE worksite_id = 'x'` (which might be the totally wrong way of focusing on one worksite)

Comment: what I meant is - you can look for `Longest Consecutive Days Count` for each user no matter which worksite that user was working on. But another option would be to look for `Longest Consecutive Days Count` for each user with extra condition of being on the same worksite during those days. I do not know nature of your data and meaning of worksite  - so provided you with two versions of query for respective options. hope this answers your follow up question :o)

Answer (score 4):

does this fit for you?

```
set @gr=1;
select uid, max(cnt) max_cnt from (
  select uid, grp, count(*) cnt from (
    select uid, 
      case when ifnull(DATE_ADD(oldDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY), timestamp)= timestamp then 
        @gr 
      else  
        @gr := @gr +1 
      end grp
    from
    (
        SELECT    
          uid, 
          timestamp, 
          lag(timestamp) over (partition by uid order by timestamp asc) as oldDate
        FROM      OnSite
    ) t
  )t2
  group by uid, grp
  )t3
group by uid
```

Result

```
| uid    | max_cnt |
| ------ | ------- |
| u1     | 2       |
| u12345 | 4       |
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/obpDs1tm1FuCbuat3QytwF/2)

Comment: I think there is some errors in the syntax, it's not running for me in the DB Fiddle

Comment: I added my Db Fiddle

Comment: Can you check the link? I'm just seeing my first query there

Comment: Yeah, your DB Fiddle only make a group by

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to fork :) I updated the link now

Comment: I dont think this is giving me the right data back. u12345 would be 4 and u1 would be 2.

Comment: Please check my answer. It now gives you expected result

Comment: Awesome work Simonare, it works as expected! Thanks for looking into this. Unfortunately doesn't work for my BigQuery purposes but I never said anything about that to you so I've marked it as correct

Comment: Still is a good answer even if it turns out not to be of use to OP.